# MAX値を記録した他のフィールド取得

Tags: sql

Microsoft SQL Server 2012を使っています。

例えば以下のようなレコードをもつテーブルがあるとします。
レコードは10分毎の1ヶ月分のデータになります。(4032Row)
DateTime, Value1, Value2
2018-02-01 00:10:00 0.3 0.3
2018-02-01 00:20:00 0.3 0.6
2018-02-01 00:30:00 0.5 1.1
2018-02-01 00:40:00 0.2 1
2018-02-01 00:50:00 0.4 1.1
2018-02-01 01:00:00 0.1 0.7
...
2018-02-28 24:00:00 0.1 0.7

ここで行いたいことは
「毎日のValue2の最大値とその時間を返す」ことです。

例えば、上の例だった場合 2/1のValue2の最大値が1.1であった場合、クエリの戻り値は
2018-02-01 00:30:00 0.5 1.1
であってほしいです。
Value2に1.1が複数ある場合は最初のレコードを最大値を記録した最初のレコードとして、DateTimeフィールド、Value1フィールドの値を受け取ります。

ここで試してみたクエリは以下の通りでした。

```SQL
SELECT FORMAT(DateTime, 'yyyyMMdd'), MAX(dblValue2) 
FROM TableA  
Group BY FORMAT(DateTime, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

これだと各日のMAX値は取れたのですが、そのMAX値を記録した日付が取得できませんでした。。

どなたか、解決するための良いクエリのご教授よろしくお願いします。

※WHILEで以下にもCみたいにプログラマブルに書けば解決はできるのですが…
せっかくなのでクエリで解決したいです。

Comment: 本家 Stack Overflow における関連質問です: ["Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/5989200)

Comment: 本家 Stack Overflow における関連質問です: ["Is there something equivalent to argmax in SQL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4556653/5989200)

Comment: 本家Stack Overflow確認しました。わかりやすい内容でした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

試してないけど...

```sql
SELECT TableA.DateTime, TableA.dblValue1, TableA.dblValue2
FROM ( SELECT MIN(TableA.DateTime) AS D2
       FROM ( SELECT FORMAT(DateTime, 'yyyyMMdd') AS D1, MAX(dblValue2) AS V1
              FROM TableA  
              GROUP BY FORMAT(DateTime, 'yyyyMMdd')
            ) AS Q1
       INNER JOIN TableA
       ON FORMAT(TableA.DateTime, 'yyyyMMdd') = Q1.D1 AND TableA.dblValue2 = Q1.V1
       GROUP BY FORMAT(TableA.DateTime, 'yyyyMMdd')
     ) AS Q2
INNER JOIN TableA
ON TableA.DateTime = Q2.D2
ORDER BY TableA.DateTime
```